# Garbled Screen after login

Tags: display

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a Sony VIAO.  After logging in (login screen works fine) I get a garbled (unreadable) screen.  The mouse does work, but as I move the mouse or click, the screen seems to change (continued garbled).  It seems like a display driver issue.  I have to re-boot to get back to the login screen.

How do I remedy this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an NVIDIA chip in this computer? If so, did you install the latest drivers from `jockey-gtk`?

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you attached a screenshot. I cannot help you, though you can try pressing

```
Ctrl+Alt+F1
```

and log in there, type

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

and then press

```
Ctrl+Alt+F7
```

and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

At root login on tty1 or 3 type:xinit gnome-session.You'll get a small white window,then wait,it will open up a gnome desktop in root!Leave the little white box alone,if you close it,desktop session goes Bybye!but you can move it out of the way or move to desktop #2 where the white box doesn't show!
David R

Comment: Also if your original login screen is garbled,change to tty1 or 3 type startx gnome-session.You'll be logged in as your default user,you may get your user name requiring password to login.but this doesn't fix first login screen,you'll have to do some editing there.

Comment: Type journalctl -xe ,you will get a report that shows state of gdm,it will show gdm entered dead state after alternate login in cli.this may help!David R

Comment: Ps you can type journalctl -xe | less,to scroll thru messages that tell you what going on!